# TeamCity "The element <ParameterGroup> beneath element <UsingTask> is unrecognized."

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

I receive the following error from an MSBuild task on TeamCity.

> `The element <ParameterGroup> beneath element <UsingTask> is
>   unrecognized.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can occur when your project is configured to use a recent version of NuGet but the MSBuild version being used by TeamCity is old and doesn't support some new NuGet features.

Change the MSBuild version and tools to at least 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Your project is targeting .NET 3.5, so to fix the problem you needed to update the visual studio version in the build configuration parameter property of TeamCity to VS2010 or VS2012.

[TeamCity build from VS2008 to VS2012](http://blog.paulhadfield.net/2012/12/upgrading-teamcity-build-from-vs2008-to.html)

Comment: It was QA: I pose a question I know the answer to but SO system sucks and doesn't mark my answer. Your answer is right (thanks) for a Solution step, mine was for an MSBuild step.

Answer (score 0):

(Already posted here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61833256/1214248 but I post it again. It might help someone here because litterature on this question is pretty much *inexistant*!)

Apart from the tooling versions, you must respect the elements positions in the XML project source file.

So : another possibility, is that you are using `<UsingTask>` inside a `<Target>` element. You MUST declare `<UsingTask>` outside the `<Target />`.

The error is the following otherwise :

```
proj(2300,5): error MSB4067: L'élément "ParameterGroup" situé sous l'élément <UsingTask> n'est pas reconnu.
```