# Error: The element <ParameterGroup> beneath element <UsingTask> is unrecognized

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I am receiving this error, when building the solution using the msbuild.

```
The element <ParameterGroup> beneath element <UsingTask> is
  unrecognized.
```

The error is showing both in msbuild and in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because one of your project is targeting .NET 3.5.
All of your projects should be targeted to .NET 4.0 at least.

If your .cs project does not allow to view or change the Target Framework, as it was in my situation: You will need to change it manually in .csproj. 
Open the .csproj in notepad.
In this line

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5"...
```

change the ToolsVersion to at least 4.0.

Comment: I know it's almost been five years but I'm now having the same issue. I'm using `dotnet cli` and `RoslynCodeTaskFactory` NuGet dependency. Got anything for me?

Comment: @Crono see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Other possibility, is that you are using `<UsingTask>` inside a `<Target>` element.

You MUST declare it outside the `<Target />`.

Tested on 2017 and 2019.

The error is the following otherwise. (I would bet this is @Crono sees with Roslyn).

```
proj(2300,5): error MSB4067: L'élément "ParameterGroup" situé sous l'élément <UsingTask> n'est pas reconnu.
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Just copy the config below and create a **specflow.exe.config** file
2. Put this config file next to your specflow.exe and you will be able to create the nunitexecutionreport report.

also can use this link https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Reporting

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<configuration> 
    <startup> 
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" /> 
    </startup> 
</configuration>
```